# How can I get values from each button in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
      <form action="posts-ayarlar.php" method="POST" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">

            
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >

                <tr>
                <thead>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">BLOG TITLE</th>                                    
                    <th scope="col">EDİT</th>
                </thead>                 
               </tr>
         <?php 
               foreach($personellist as $person){   
                   $xasr=$person->id;    
         ?>
         
              <tr>
                  <tbody>
                     <td><?= $person->id ?> </td>
                     <td><?= $person->title ?></td>
                     <td><button  type="submit" name="post_ayar_guncelle_<?php echo $xasr ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Güncelle</button> </td>
                     <input type="hidden" name="giden" value="<?= $person->id ?>"/>
                  </tbody>          
              </tr>
   
             
         <?php } ?>
   
   </table>
   </form>
```

---

The process page, you can see 8 at the left top corner it is a value that is coming from the main edit table page.

```
<?php include 'connectionconfig.php'; 
 $gelen=$_POST["giden"];
 $sorgu=$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts where id:id');
 $sorgu->execute(array('id'=>$gelen));
 $personellist=$sorgu-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

          //example edit section

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Blog Title <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" name="title" id="first-name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $personellist['title']; ?>">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

**The idea is**
When I click one of these buttons I want to go to process.php with that button id and then I can call back the data where is the id, so the web page will show edit blog page which has button id. But when I click any button of these the value returns 8 because of foreach loop.

**By the way;**
I already used ajax but I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM posts where id:id'` has a syntax error, missing `=` sign between `id` and `:id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buttons don't have values, but your hidden inputs do.

**All** the hidden inputs' values will be submitted, but since the name doesn't end in `[]` only one won't be discarded by PHP.

- Get rid of the hidden inputs
- Store the values on the buttons

Only the clicked submit button will be successful and submit its data.

```
<td>
  <button 
    class="btn btn-primary"
    name="giden"
    value="<?= htmlspecialchars($person->id) ?>"/>
  >
    Güncelle
  </button>
</td>
```

---

You should also [use a validator](https://validator.nu/) on your generated HTML as you have a number of errors.

A `tbody` element can't go inside a `tr` element (and it wouldn't make sense anyway, the point of `tbody` is to **group** a set of `tr` elements!).

`input` elements can't be children of `tr` or `tbody` elements. If they appear inside a table, then must be inside a cell of that table. It doesn't matter if they are hidden or not.

Comment: But how can I call back that value on the process page?  example : $value=$_POST['value']

Comment: You use its name … like you **already are**: `$gelen=$_POST["giden"];`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the mistake, now it's worked.